# show/hide div during business hours, mix with UTC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

## **UPDATE**

I have added a current working fiddle, I feel like it should be correct, but it doesn't seem to work.

## https://jsfiddle.net/bill9000/yadk6sja/2/

## *original question:*

what I have is some code to show/hide div (basically show div during certain business hours) - is there an easy way to make this use a calculate from UTC... so that the show/hide time is fixed on a certain timezone. eg. 6pm EST instead of 6pm users time...  here's my current code:

```
var d = new Date();
var dayOfWeek = d.getDay();
var hour = d.getHours();
var mins = d.getMinutes();
var status = 'open';

if (dayOfWeek !== 6 && dayOfWeek !== 0 && hour >= 03 && hour < 15){
//if (hour=='10' && mins < '30'){
   // status = 'closed';
 // }else{
   status = 'open';
 // }
}else{
status = 'closed';

if (status=='open') {
$b('.orderby').show();
}else{
$b('.orderby').hide();
}
```

also, I have some other JavaScript that's getting the UTC diff:

```
function ShowTime()  {
 var now = new Date();
 var diff = now.getTimezoneOffset() / 60; //the difference between local PC and UTC
 diff = diff - 4; //the difference between UTC and EST

  var hrs = 18-(now.getHours()+diff); //18 is the target hour
```

any way of making the show/hide work for the specific time?

Comment: I recommend you convert your store hours to UTC and then compare to the UTC time on the client by using getUTCDay(), getUTCHours(), getUTCMinutes(). Then, there is no need to compute the offsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date()` objects are already UTC, when you use `d.getDay()` or `d.getHours()`, the local timezone is applied on the fly.

You just have to use `d.getUTCDay()`, `d.getUTCHours()`, etc. to prevent this

Comment: so is this right then if I use d.getUTCDay(), d.getUTCHours() ? if (dayOfWeek !== 6 && dayOfWeek !== 0 && hour >= 03 && hour < 15){

Comment: Yes. The change would be in the declaration of dayOfWeek and hour.

Comment: thanks! I updated the original question with a fiddle, but it still doesn't seem to work.